# How to make git automerge non conflicting changes?

Tags: git

I merged one branch into current and get a lot of "both modified:" messages. Example:

> Unmerged paths:
>     (use "git add ..." to mark resolution)

```
    both modified:   mp/src/game/client/c_baseplayer.h
    both modified:   mp/src/game/client/c_colorcorrection.cpp
    both modified:   mp/src/game/client/c_dynamiclight.cpp
    both modified:   mp/src/game/client/c_team_train_watcher.cpp
    both modified:   mp/src/game/client/c_vehicle_jeep.cpp
    both modified:   mp/src/game/client/cdll_client_int.cpp
    both modified:   mp/src/game/client/clientmode_shared.cpp
    both modified:   mp/src/game/client/episodic/c_npc_advisor.cpp
    both modified:   mp/src/game/client/episodic/c_prop_scalable.cpp
    both modified:   mp/src/game/client/fx_impact.cpp
    both modified:   mp/src/game/client/game_controls/baseviewport.cpp
    both modified:   mp/src/game/client/game_controls/classmenu.cpp
    both modified:   mp/src/game/client/game_controls/vguitextwindow.cpp
```

Now if I run `git mergetool` DiffMerge successfully merges each file with me manually clicking on OK, Save, Next. Is there a way to enable it to automerge all these files automatically and only show files which can't be automerged? Just like TortoiseSvn does.

Commands I run:

```
git clone https://github.com/ValveSoftware/source-sdk-2013.git
cd source-sdk-2013/
git remote add seco https://github.com/whoozzem/SecobMod.git
git fetch seco
git merge seco/master
git mergetool
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "non-conflicting", `both modified` means there *are* conflicts between the branches. Do you wish to keep changes from only one branch for those files?

Comment: It might be something as simple as different lineendings which the merge tool you use do not consider.

Comment: @ojrask, by "non-conflicting file" I mean a file that can be merged by a program without human interaction. See, changes made in each branch don't overlap and I can't understand why these files are marked as conflicted by git.

Comment: Merging is not something provided by an OS kernel or a common library, so Git and your merge tool implement different merge algorythms and/or implement them in different ways and/or have different settings for them.  What @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen said looks perfectly reasonable so I'd check that.  But things like lines of context to check might affect the outcome.  Also note that Git uses 3-way merging, if possible; not sure if your merge tool does the same, and this might affect the result as well.